# How to use php in the header?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to use the php code in the header but it does not work.

**This is the code I am using.**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
$tabs['test_tab'] = array(
'title' => __( '<span>Hot</span>' . 'Title' , 'woocommerce' ),
'priority' => 50,
'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);return $tabs;}
```

[image]

**How can you use html for "Title"**

**It seems that printing "html" code does not work**
**when I used my code the title was printed as: `"<span> Hot </ hot> Title"`**

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I used to add a new tab named Title. It works fine in the sub-function, but I'm trying to use a php script next to that header

Comment: Is not possible to add html tags in the button tab text string as they are not rendered.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec How can you use html for "Title", thank you

Comment: Title as in the head element or title of a page?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs this is an element from a tab menu and html tags aren't rendered anyway… it's the tab menu on single product pages of woocommerce. So there is no way to include a `<span>` tag or any other html tag…

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I want to use html in <span> Title </span>

Comment: @LoicTheAztec As you say there is no other way to use html?

Comment: No way to use html tags in single product tabs menu items… they are not rendered as html… You should need to change the html structure, but this will break the tabs functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );

function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
    'title' => __( 'Title' , 'woocommerce_tab_custom_title' ),
    'priority' => 50,
    'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: My code is active. but i want to use php edge from "title", you can do something there.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I changed the content to be more detailed, when I used my code the title was printed as: "<span> Hot </ hot> Title"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to hook into `wp_head` using `add_action` like the following example:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'woo_new_product_tab');
function woo_new_product_tab() {
    <?php
    <title>
        Hot
    </title>
    ?>
}
```

Comment: Make sure the callback is not a function that you are using before.

Comment: I certainly do not use the same function before